# Why does my multidimensional vector only push_back 0 index?

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I having a problem using `push_back()`, I can't figure out why only the first `cols` vector is just pushed over and over again.

**Input**

`10 9 10 3 100 8 7 10 73 9 10 5 9 87 -1 8 3 7 10 92 6 10 6 83 9 11 8 8 77 -1 10 10 10 10 100 10 10 10 100 10 10 10 10 100 -1 DONE`

**C++**

```
(...)

size = numbers.size();
counter = 0;
square = ceil(sqrt(size));
vector < vector <int> > rows;
vector<int> cols;

do {
    for (int i = 0; i < square; ++i) {
        cols.push_back(numbers[counter]);
        cout << cols[i] << " ";
        ++counter;
    }
    rows.push_back(cols);
    cout << endl;
} while (counter <= size);
(...)
```

**Undesirable Output**

```
0:   10   9  10   3 100   8   7
1:   10   9  10   3 100   8   7
2:   10   9  10   3 100   8   7
3:   10   9  10   3 100   8   7
4:   10   9  10   3 100   8   7
5:   10   9  10   3 100   8   7
6:   10   9  10   3 100   8   7
```

`rows[1][2]` should be `73`, not `9`. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset `cols`. Instead you just keep adding on to it. I think you are printing `rows` out with magic number indices, which is why you do not spot the added portion. Either declare a temporary `cols` inside the loop or call `clear` after each `push_back()`.

Comment: Ah, good advice. I used `cols.clear()` and it worked, but why doesn't the contents of the vector just get over-written like any other variable?

Comment: Your `pushing_back()` which means that it adds on to the `vector` and increases its size.

Comment: So the new additions to the vector never get copied into the parent vector because they exceed `square` (`7`, in this case)?

Comment: They do. You are probably just not printing them out.

Answer (score 0):

awesomeyi found your main problem. But your code has other issues too.

There is a buffer overflow. For example if `size == 4` then `square == 2`
and we get:

- after iter #1: counter == `2`; continue since 2 <= 4
- after iter #2: counter == `4`; continue since 4 <= 4
- iter #3: reads `numbers[4]` and `numbers[5]` - oops!

The loop condition should be:

```
while (counter + square <= size);
```

we need to make sure that the next iteration will complete without overflowing the vector. It would be smart to use `.at()` for vector access so that if you did make a miscalculation, then the error will behave nicely instead of going screwball.

The loop (minus the output) could actually be written as:

```
for (size_t counter = 0; counter + square <= size; counter += square )
{
    std::vector<int> cols( numbers.begin() + counter, numbers.begin() + counter + square );
    rows.push_back(cols);
}
```